# the edit toolbar does not appear when I try to edit a question

Tags: support, edits, javascript

The screenie says it all.

When I clicked *"Ask Question"* the edit title appears, but when I tried to edit a question the edit toolbar just doesn't appear at all.

I'm using Chrome 9. I tried IE9 but my internet connection got dicey and I couldn't manage to login with my OpenID

I'm on a Win7x64. Here is the screenie
[image]

**Update**

Ok, somehow its all fine on my laptop. Windows 7 x64.

Comment: You probably have some out-of-date JavaScript on your other machine. Does it work after ctrl-f5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that somehow your javascript browser cache is inexplicably out of date. Try clearing your cache with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jeff. Yes I did clear my cache before I posted itself, but somehow **it worked** after a restart a few hours later, my pc has been acting a little strange lately, IE9 renders a few random websites in bold!